# Why does DNS work the way it does?

Tags: domain-name-system

> This is a [Canonical Question](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/1986) about DNS (Domain Name Service).

If my understanding of the DNS system is correct, the .com registry holds a table that maps domains (www.example.com) to DNS servers.

1. What is the advantage? Why not map directly to an IP address?
2. If the only record that needs to change when I am configuring a DNS server to point to a different IP address, is located at the DNS server, why isn't the process instant?
3. If the only reason for the delay are DNS caches, is it possible to bypass them, so I can see what is happening in real time?

Comment: To all the people trying to migrate/close this question: Please leave it here. It has a home here, where it can be loved and tenderly cared for. And we can point all "How does DNS Work" questions here as a canonical answer, because this one is extremely well answered.

Comment: `You can not able full understand DNS unless you are name Paul Mockapetris, Paul Vixie or Cricket Liu.` https://twitter.com/DEVOPS_BORAT/status/249006925767909376

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Actually, it's more complicated than that - rather than one "central registry (that) holds a table that maps domains (www.mysite.com) to DNS servers", there are several layers of hierarchy

There's a central registry (the Root Servers) which contain only a small set of entries: the NS (nameserver) records for all the top-level domains - `.com`, `.net`, `.org`, `.uk`, `.us`, `.au`, and so on.

Those servers just contain NS records for the next level down. To pick one example, the nameservers for the `.uk` domain just has entries for `.co.uk`, `.ac.uk`, and the other second-level zones in use in the UK.

Those servers just contain NS records for the next level down - to continue the example, they tell you where to find the NS records for `google.co.uk`. It's on those servers that you'll finally find a mapping between a hostname like `www.google.co.uk` and an IP address.

As an extra wrinkle, each layer will also serve up 'glue' records. Each NS record maps a domain to a hostname - for instance, the NS records for `.uk` list `nsa.nic.uk` as one of the servers. To get to the next level, we need to find out the NS records for `nic.uk` are, and they turn out to include `nsa.nic.uk` as well. So now we need to know the IP of `nsa.nic.uk`, but to find that out we need to make a query to `nsa.nic.uk`, but we can't make that query until we know the IP for `nsa.nic.uk`...

To resolve this quandary, the servers for `.uk` add the A record for `nsa.nic.uk` into the `ADDITIONAL SECTION` of the response (response below trimmed for brevity):

```
jamezpolley@li101-70:~$dig nic.uk ns

; <<>> DiG 9.7.0-P1 <<>> nic.uk ns
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 21768
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 11, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 14

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;nic.uk.                IN  NS

;; ANSWER SECTION:
nic.uk.         172800  IN  NS  nsb.nic.uk.
nic.uk.         172800  IN  NS  nsa.nic.uk.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
nsa.nic.uk.     172800  IN  A   156.154.100.3
nsb.nic.uk.     172800  IN  A   156.154.101.3
```

Without these extra glue records, we'd never be able to find the nameservers for `nic.uk.` and so we'd never be able to look up any domains hosted there.

To get back to your questions...

> a) What is the advantage? Why not map directly to an IP address?

For one thing, it allows edits to each individual zone to be distributed. If you want to update the entry for `www.mydomain.co.uk`, you just need to edit the information on your `mydomain.co.uk`'s nameserver. There's no need to notify the central `.co.uk` servers, or the `.uk` servers, or the root nameservers. If there was only a single central registry that mapped all the levels all the way down the hierarchy that had to be notified about every single change of a DNS entry all the way down the chain, it would be absolutely swamped with traffic.

Before 1982, this was actually how name resolution happened. One central registry was notified about all updates, and they distributed a file called `hosts.txt` which contained the hostname and IP address of every machine on the internet. A new version of this file was published every few weeks, and every machine on the internet would have to download a new copy. Well before 1982, this was starting to become problematic, and so DNS was invented to provide a more distributed system.

For another thing, this would be a Single Point of Failure - if the single central registry went down, the entire internet would be offline. Having a distributed system means that failures only affect small sections of the internet, not the whole thing.

(To provide extra redundancy, there are actually 13 separate clusters of servers that serve the root zone. Any changes to the top-level domain records have to be pushed to all 13; imagine having to coordinate updating all 13 of them for every single change to any hostname anywhere in the world...)

> b) If the only record that needs to change when I am configuring a DNS
>   server to point to a different IP address is located at the DNS
>   server, why isn't the process instant?

Because DNS utilises a lot of caching to both speed things up and decrease the load on the NSes. Without caching, every single time you visited `google.co.uk` your computer would have to go out to the network to look up the servers for `.uk`, then `.co.uk`, then `.google.co.uk`, then `www.google.co.uk`. Those answers don't actually change much, so looking them up every time is a waste of time and network traffic. Instead, when the NS returns records to your computer, it will include a TTL value, that tells your computer to cache the results for a number of seconds.

For example, the NS records for `.uk` have a TTL of 172800 seconds - 2 days. Google are even more conservative - the NS records for `google.co.uk` have a TTL of 4 days. Services which rely on being able to update quickly can choose a much lower TTL - for instance, `telegraph.co.uk` has a TTL of just 600 seconds on their NS records.

If you want updates to your zone to be near-instant, you can choose to lower your TTL as far down as you like. The lower your set it, the more traffic your servers will see, as clients refresh their records more often. Every time a client has to contact your servers to do a query, this will cause some lag as it's slower than looking up the answer on their local cache, so you'll also want to consider the tradeoff between fast updates and a fast service.

> c) If the only reason for the delay are DNS caches, is it possible to
>   bypass them, so I can see what is happening in real time?

Yes, this is easy if you're testing manually with `dig` or similar tools - just tell it which server to contact.

Here's an example of a cached response:

```
jamezpolley@host:~$dig telegraph.co.uk NS

; <<>> DiG 9.7.0-P1 <<>> telegraph.co.uk NS
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 36675
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 8, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;telegraph.co.uk.       IN  NS

;; ANSWER SECTION:
telegraph.co.uk.    319 IN  NS  ns1-63.akam.net.
telegraph.co.uk.    319 IN  NS  eur3.akam.net.
telegraph.co.uk.    319 IN  NS  use2.akam.net.
telegraph.co.uk.    319 IN  NS  usw2.akam.net.
telegraph.co.uk.    319 IN  NS  use4.akam.net.
telegraph.co.uk.    319 IN  NS  use1.akam.net.
telegraph.co.uk.    319 IN  NS  usc4.akam.net.
telegraph.co.uk.    319 IN  NS  ns1-224.akam.net.

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 97.107.133.4#53(97.107.133.4)
;; WHEN: Thu Feb  2 05:46:02 2012
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 198
```

The flags section here doesn't contain the `aa` flag, so we can see that this result came from a cache rather than directly from an authoritative source. In fact, we can see that it came from `97.107.133.4`, which happens to be one of Linode's local DNS resolvers. The fact that the answer was served out of a cache very close to me means that it took 0msec for me to get an answer; but as we'll see in a moment, the price I pay for that speed is that the answer is almost 5 minutes out of date.

To bypass Linode's resolver and go straight to the source, just pick one of those NSes and tell dig to contact it directly:

```
jamezpolley@li101-70:~$dig @ns1-224.akam.net telegraph.co.uk NS

; <<>> DiG 9.7.0-P1 <<>> @ns1-224.akam.net telegraph.co.uk NS
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 23013
;; flags: qr aa rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 8, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;telegraph.co.uk.       IN  NS

;; ANSWER SECTION:
telegraph.co.uk.    600 IN  NS  use2.akam.net.
telegraph.co.uk.    600 IN  NS  eur3.akam.net.
telegraph.co.uk.    600 IN  NS  use1.akam.net.
telegraph.co.uk.    600 IN  NS  ns1-63.akam.net.
telegraph.co.uk.    600 IN  NS  usc4.akam.net.
telegraph.co.uk.    600 IN  NS  ns1-224.akam.net.
telegraph.co.uk.    600 IN  NS  usw2.akam.net.
telegraph.co.uk.    600 IN  NS  use4.akam.net.

;; Query time: 9 msec
;; SERVER: 193.108.91.224#53(193.108.91.224)
;; WHEN: Thu Feb  2 05:48:47 2012
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 198
```

You can see that this time, the results were served directly from the source - note the `aa` flag, which indicates that the results came from an authoritative source. In my earlier example, the results came from my local cache, so they lack the `aa` flag. I can see that the authoritative source for this domain sets a TTL of 600 seconds. The results I got earlier from a local cache had a TTL of just 319 seconds, which tells me that they'd been sitting in the cache for (600-319) seconds - almost 5 minutes - before I saw them.

Although the TTL here is only 600 seconds, some ISPs will attempt to reduce their traffic even further by forcing their DNS resolvers to cache the results for longer - in some cases, for 24 hours or more. It's traditional (in a we-don't-know-if-this-is-really-neccessary-but-let's-be-safe kind of way) to assume that any DNS change you make won't be visible everywhere on the internet for 24-48 hours.

Comment: +1 That is one awesome explanation. Will definitely bookmark this!

Comment: The real answer to whether a DNS response came from a cache or not is in the "flags" section of the answer. There's no technical reason why one couldn't set a TTL of, say, 319 seconds. Instead, look for the `aa` (authoritative answer) `flag` in the response. If `aa` is present, the answer came directly from an authoritative name server. (If it's missing, the answer *may* still be fresh; some recursive name servers clear the `aa` flag before passing on the response to the client resolver.)

Comment: Also, for figuring things out, I tend to use dig's `+norec` and `+trace` options quite a bit. "norec" says to not perform any recursion in name resolution (clearing the `rd` or `recursion desired` bit in the query; note that even if `rd`, DNS servers may not offer recursion to you, indicated by the lack of `ra` recursion available in the response). "trace" says start at the root name servers as obtained from your system's resolver and do the recursion manually, printing the intermediate results.

Comment: You should note that some ISPs will cache DNS records for much longer than the TTL says that they should, so even with very short TTLs you can't guarantee that all at sites visitors will get the correct IP for a day or two after you relocate a site.

Comment: They should put this up on the serverfault blog

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Yes, good catch. I was only trying to point out that my local machine was keeping track of the TTL, but I didn't explain that well. Also, I didn't realise dig had a `+trace` option!

Comment: as a follow up answer, can we have why the dns doesn't work.

Comment: @JamesPolley there's a (minor) error in your explanation with your use of the `.uk` servers.  Currently the Nominet-managed second level domains are on the same servers as `uk.`, so a query for `example.co.uk` to the `uk` servers will receive a delegation immediately without having to first go through a delegation to the `co.uk` servers.

Comment: Note that dig's `+trace` option will query your configured nameserver for the root nameservers, so that it can start searching. If your local nameserver is `dnsmasq` (as on Ubuntu), it doesn't support this, so you'll get an error. Use `dig +trace @8.8.8.8 www.example.com`. 8.8.8.8 is Google's public DNS service. Use 1.1.1.1 for Cloudflare's equivalent.

Answer (score 9):

a) The number of IP --> host name mappings in the world is REALLY big.  This system distributes the responsibility of hosting all the subdomain and MX records and every other DNS record out to the owner of the domain name.  This was pretty much the point of the domain name.  `.com` is held by one registry where as `.uk` can be held by another.  Likewise `example.com` and `otherexample.com` can be hosted separately so the resources can be distributed.

b)  It's cached, which reduces the number of hits on your DNS host down to a small fraction of what it would be otherwise.  By default records live 2 days in the cache before being discarded.  This can be changed by altering the TTL (time to live) of the record.

c) You can effectively stop records being cached by setting a really short TTL.  This is **NOT** recommend unless you're using it for dynamic DNS.  Caching drops the hits on the DNS server by a lot.  To pick a guessed number out of the air we're talking about knocking off 95% of the requests.

Comment: Regarding 'C', be careful. Set that TTL low enough and your DNS server might get hammered. Not a huge issue if someone other than you is handling DNS.

Comment: So if it weren't for subdomains, there wouldn't be much of an advantage

Comment: Perhapse, but remeber even `yourdomain.com` is a subdomain of `.com`.  If it was just one big "hosts file" (as it was before DNS and elves still walked in middle earth) then yes.  You'd just have one big file and everyone would cache that.

Comment: Um, yes? It's true, if the DNS namespace was flat and contained no delegations, it would be better-implemented as a single list held in one place. However it was designed to be hierachical and thus delegatable.

Comment: The DNS namespace *was* flat, with no delegations, for a long time; and it *was* implemented as a single list, held in one place. That became unworkable and got replaced by DNS in 1982...

Comment: James - yup, I'm quite aware of that :-) That was before it was DNS, which is my point.

Comment: @mfinni, Well, it's "domain name system", not "distributed name system" or anything like that. Of course it's designed to be distributable, but there's nothing saying that you absolutely *have* to run it that way. For some small office networks with no global connectivity, having everything in a root zone (or a single TLD such as `local`) probably makes some limited amount of sense.

Answer (score 3):

If you're on a *nix system, download a copy of Dan Bernstein's djbdns from http://cr.yp.to/djbdns.html and run his dnstrace program to see how the recursive query system works.  Its very informative.

Comment: Will it allow me to see the effect of a configuration change instantly?

Comment: dnstrace (usually through dnstracesort) gives intense amounts of detail  about the DNS configuration for any domain and query you make.  If the server has made a change, they will show the change and how it has propagated.  They're excellent for tracing propagation errors as well.

Comment: You can as well run `dig +trace` command, with `dig`, even if coming out of bind source code, being installed quite often everywhere. Basic DNS troubleshooting tool.

Answer (score 3):

a)  The number of possible domain names is way too large for one server to handle.  And there's not just .com; there's .net, .org, .se, .info, and any number of others.  Add to that, you can delegate responsibility for a subdomain (which is effectively what `com` does).  DNS being less centralized makes all that easier to manage.

b)  Machines along the way from the user to you have DNS caches in order to minimize the number of requests needed.  It prevents, for example, spamming the network with requests for the address of "serverfault.com" every time you get a page from SF.  Those servers can even cache "domain doesn't exist" results, which is why it can take a while for even a brand new domain to show up.

c) Although you can disable your cache, there are often other DNS servers between your machine and yourdomain.com's DNS server.  Your ISP's DNS server, for example, will try to cache as much as it can.  The only records that get updated relatively quickly around the net are ones with a short TTL (which basically says "i'm only valid for a few seconds; after that, ask me again for current info").  The reason TTLs are so high, though, is so that the server responsible for the domain can offload some of the work to other servers.  If you had all the net contacting your one or two rinky-dink DNS servers for every hit to your web site, they'd be pretty much unusable the second someone saw your site on /., digg, etc.

Comment: Your (c) is wrong.  It's a widespread misunderstanding of DNS.  [There's no chain of servers — local machine to router to ISP to … — each contacting the next in line.](http://superuser.com/a/378653/38062)  Requests go from a DNS client (library), through a _single_ resolving proxy DNS server, to zero or more content DNS servers.  Barring the existence of forwarding proxy DNS servers, **that's it**.

Comment: @JdeBP: It's a "widespread misunderstanding" because as far as i've seen in the real world, *it's largely true*.  If you get your address via DHCP, as just about everyone does, then you've almost certainly been given the address of a DNS server that you're supposed to use.  Which, in home networks, is almost always the router -- which is basically forwarding to your ISP's DNS.  And in small business networks, is usually the domain controller -- which, again, is usually forwarding to the ISP's DNS.  It's generally at that point that the iterative stuff takes over.

Comment: You need to see more of the real world if you think "largely true" fits at all. I actually mentioned forwarding proxies as the one extra item. However, you're overestimating their use in business networks; and indeed overestimating how many change their domain controllers from the default, which is (after one has removed any root zone) a _resolving_ DNS server using root hints. Your basic error in (c) remains uncorrected. Disabling a cache doesn't magically reveal a cache "behind" it. The DNS simply doesn't work that way. If you aren't misunderstanding it, then you are misrepresenting it.

Comment: The fact is, if you disable the cache on your local machine, you still see the results that are cached by your local network's DNS server.  And if you disable that, you're still likely to have your ISP's cache to worry about.  Whether you accept that as a common case or not, it's the case i've seen just about every time -- which makes it common enough to be well worth mentioning.

Comment: @cHao most CPE DNS servers only "forward" and don't cache.

Answer (score 1):

James's answer is good, but is now 10 years old and I think there are some points worth revisiting, and I prefer to state them here rather than editing his answer.

## A dot is not necessarily a delegation

> Those servers just contain NS records for the next level down. To pick one example, the nameservers for the .uk domain just has entries for .co.uk, .ac.uk, and the other second-level zones in use in the UK.

Maybe it was just to trim things down, but out of caution, there is a very widespread misrepresentation that exists and needs to be fixed as it creates various other misunderstanding.

A dot in a name does not imply necessarily delegation (`NS` records).

It is the case here and now for the example given as shown below:

```
$ dig uk. NS +short
dns1.nic.uk.
nsc.nic.uk.
dns3.nic.uk.
dns2.nic.uk.
nsb.nic.uk.
nsa.nic.uk.
dns4.nic.uk.
nsd.nic.uk.
$ dig @dns1.nic.uk. co.uk. NS +short
nsa.nic.uk.
nsb.nic.uk.
nsc.nic.uk.
nsd.nic.uk.
dns1.nic.uk.
dns2.nic.uk.
dns3.nic.uk.
dns4.nic.uk.
```

but there are counter-examples, like `gouv.fr` is **NOT** delegated out of `fr` (no `NS` records) as it can be seen below (yet both zones are managed by the same organization):

```
$ dig fr. NS +short
g.ext.nic.fr.
d.nic.fr.
f.ext.nic.fr.
e.ext.nic.fr.
$ dig @d.nic.fr. gouv.fr. NS +short
$
```

No display indeed, because the full reply is only:

```
;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
fr.         1h30m IN SOA nsmaster.nic.fr. hostmaster.nic.fr. (
```

showing that `gouv.fr` is not delegated out of `fr`.

So in short, at any level of the DNS you may have any name defined below (the owner of the zone `example.com` can completely publish a record for `foo.bar.buz.example.com` if he wishes, without having to have any `NS` records anywhere "in the middle"), OR delegation at any point (the owner of the zone `example.com` can delegate `foo.bar.example.com` but not `bar.example.com` for example).

## Glue records

> As an extra wrinkle, each layer will also serve up 'glue' records.

Again, this may be just oversimplification in text, but as it stands, is not true.

First glue records appear only if there is delegation. For the reasons of the previous point, not all layers have delegations for names below.

Then glues exist and are needed **ONLY** if the nameservers used are in-bailiwick.

If `example.com` is delegated to `ns1.example.com` then the authoritative nameserver for `com` NEEDS to publish both the `NS` records and `A`/`AAAA` records directly for `ns1.example.com`. Those ones are called glue records, for the simple fact that they are at the parent side where they concern the name at the child side.

On the contrary, if `example.com` is delegated to `ns1.provider.example` then there is **NO** glue records in the `com` authoritative nameservers, that will publish only the `NS` record.

For further discussions and details on that, please refer to [RFC 8499 "DNS Terminology"](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8499) that has a whole section on glues and "in-bailiwick" nameservers, starting at §7. Zones.

Just other related quick observations:

- there are both advantages and drawbacks in using glue records; the sane recommendation would be for any given important name to use a mixture of nameservers, where some are in-bailiwick (hence needing glues) and some are not; that way you theoretically dampen the disadvantages of each case
- glue records are a problem in a DNSSEC world as they are in the `ADDITIONAL` section which is NOT signed, hence can be tampered with, even if both the parent and the child are fully DNSSEC enabled (which is why having all nameservers as in-bailiwick is a security risk in that regard)

## `hosts.txt` "database"

> Before 1982, this was actually how name resolution happened. One central registry was notified about all updates, and they distributed a file called hosts.txt which contained the hostname and IP address of every machine on the internet.

Yes indeed. And you can see how it looked like by going to https://rscott.org/OldInternetFiles/ that collected old versions of that file.

For example, the earliest one of 1983 has lines like that (the syntax changed over time):

```
HOST : 14.0.0.4 : UCL-VTEST ::::
HOST : 14.0.0.6 : UK-SATNET ::::
HOST : 14.0.0.7 : WISC-IBM : IBM-4341 : VM/CMS : TCP/TELNET,TCP/FTP,TCP/SMTP,ICMP :
HOST : 14.0.0.8 : RAND-TN : VAX-11/750 : UNIX : TCP/FTP,TCP/SMTP,TCP/TELNET :
HOST : 14.0.0.11 : CHALMERS-SUNET ::::
```

## TTLs

> If you want updates to your zone to be near-instant, you can choose to lower your TTL as far down as you like.

In theory, yes, in practice, no.
Otherwise, some could be tempted to put 0 or 1 (second) and think it will hence mean no cache.

In practice, big DNS operators have to defend against that because it would increase their load significantly for no real good reasons (the DNS was never expected to work as a way to do "instantaneous" fail-over operations, those considerations are to be taken higher in the stack and closer to the real application being concerned by some kind of high speed change of traffic destination), hence, and even if it is in theory against the standard, too small values will be increased.

It is hard to know exactly who does what here, but I think a reasonable ballpark is to say that under "5 minutes" for TTLs it might not be respected by resolvers. So don't use anything lower than 300.

Pro-tip in `dig`: use the `+ttlunits` option (pro-tip in the pro-tip: put the option once for all in your `~/.digrc` file and you never have to type it again) for nicer outputs of TTLs.

As in:

```
$ dig serverfault.com A +noall +ans +nottlunits
serverfault.com.    291 IN A 151.101.1.69
serverfault.com.    291 IN A 151.101.193.69
serverfault.com.    291 IN A 151.101.129.69
serverfault.com.    291 IN A 151.101.65.69
```

vs

```
$ dig serverfault.com A +noall +ans +ttlunits
serverfault.com.    4m56s IN A 151.101.193.69
serverfault.com.    4m56s IN A 151.101.1.69
serverfault.com.    4m56s IN A 151.101.129.69
serverfault.com.    4m56s IN A 151.101.65.69
```

## Bypass TTLs

> Yes, this is easy if you're testing manually with dig or similar tools - just tell it which server to contact.

More precisely, and also to enforce a very important concept, you need to query **authoritative** nameservers, before querying **recursive** ones when you are doing any kind of DNS troubleshooting.

Authoritative nameservers have the data. The reply they will give will always have the exact same TTL no matter how much and how often you ask.

A recurisve nameserver, on the contrary, is almost always running with a cache, and hence tries to answer the queries first from cache to do less network calls. The cache is controlled by TTLs on records (+ local policies). So each time you ask a recursive nameserver you will see answers with different (decreasing in fact, up to cache eviction and then back to original value or close to it) TTLs.

Example:

1. First querying its (one of them) authoritative nameserver:

```
$ dig NS serverfault.com +short
ns-cloud-c2.googledomains.com.
ns-860.awsdns-43.net.
ns-1135.awsdns-13.org.
ns-cloud-c1.googledomains.com.

$ date; dig @ns-1135.awsdns-13.org. serverfault.com A +noall +ans
Fri Jul 29 18:06:39 EST 2022
serverfault.com.    5m IN A 151.101.65.69
serverfault.com.    5m IN A 151.101.1.69
serverfault.com.    5m IN A 151.101.129.69
serverfault.com.    5m IN A 151.101.193.69
$ date; dig @ns-1135.awsdns-13.org. serverfault.com A +noall +ans
Fri Jul 29 18:06:42 EST 2022
serverfault.com.    5m IN A 151.101.129.69
serverfault.com.    5m IN A 151.101.1.69
serverfault.com.    5m IN A 151.101.193.69
serverfault.com.    5m IN A 151.101.65.69
 date; dig @ns-1135.awsdns-13.org. serverfault.com A +noall +ans
Fri Jul 29 18:06:49 EST 2022
serverfault.com.    5m IN A 151.101.1.69
serverfault.com.    5m IN A 151.101.65.69
serverfault.com.    5m IN A 151.101.129.69
serverfault.com.    5m IN A 151.101.193.69
```

Aside, astute readers will observe that 1) I used `+ttlunits` implicitely (in configuration file) and 2) the **order** of the records do change, which is a very important point as DNS deals with **sets** not **lists** hence there is no fixed order.

2. Now doing the same thing but querying a specific big public DNS resolver:

```
$ date; dig @8.8.8.8 serverfault.com A +noall +ans
Fri Jul 29 18:08:45 EST 2022
serverfault.com.    5m IN A 151.101.129.69
serverfault.com.    5m IN A 151.101.193.69
serverfault.com.    5m IN A 151.101.1.69
serverfault.com.    5m IN A 151.101.65.69
$ date; dig @8.8.8.8 serverfault.com A +noall +ans
Fri Jul 29 18:08:48 EST 2022
serverfault.com.    4m38s IN A 151.101.65.69
serverfault.com.    4m38s IN A 151.101.193.69
serverfault.com.    4m38s IN A 151.101.1.69
serverfault.com.    4m38s IN A 151.101.129.69
$ date; dig @8.8.8.8 serverfault.com A +noall +ans
Fri Jul 29 18:08:53 EST 2022
serverfault.com.    5m IN A 151.101.129.69
serverfault.com.    5m IN A 151.101.193.69
serverfault.com.    5m IN A 151.101.65.69
serverfault.com.    5m IN A 151.101.1.69
$ date; dig @8.8.8.8 serverfault.com A +noall +ans
Fri Jul 29 18:08:58 EST 2022
serverfault.com.    4m54s IN A 151.101.129.69
serverfault.com.    4m54s IN A 151.101.193.69
serverfault.com.    4m54s IN A 151.101.65.69
serverfault.com.    4m54s IN A 151.101.1.69
```

Astute readers will observe that indeed the TTLs are not constant anymore, but are also not strictly monotonically decreasing. This can be explained by the fact that using a big public resolver I may be hitting in fact different instances of it each time, that use different caches, and hence the state kept and retrieved to get my reply might not be same.