# How are A record for webhost website is found from nameserver?

Tags: domain-name-system, nameserver

I add SOA and nameservr to my zone file. When I ran DNS lookup I found unknown A record     (31.170.162.67) and MX information. See here: http://network-tools.com/default.asp?prog=dnsrec&host=jumaat.cheapantivirus.me

Is there anyway I could get the same information from command tool. Since I'm just adding nameserver and need A record to be added to my DNS zone I was hoping I could made the automated process of getting A and MX record from webhost and pasted it to my DNS zone.

See my zone file:

```
root@server1:/etc/bind# cat pri.jumaat.cheapantivirus.me
$TTL        7200
@       IN      SOA     ns01.000webhost.com. hadi.blablajkjhjkh.com. (
                        2012020402       ; serial, todays date + todays serial #
                        28800              ; refresh, seconds
                        7200              ; retry, seconds
                        604800              ; expire, seconds
                        7200 )            ; minimum, seconds
;

jumaat.cheapantivirus.me. 7200      NS        ns01.000webhost.com.
jumaat.cheapantivirus.me. 7200      NS        ns02.000webhost.com.
```

Right now my website can't propagate because no A record is added.

Comment: The question is unclear. Are you looking for some automated way to populate your zone file?

Comment: @Massimo yes. By using IP from webhost nameserver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see, with small delay between request, **two different A-data** for NSes of domain jumaat.cheapantivirus.me

Do you know it?

BTW, 000 is *terrible unreliable* in any job. JFYI, two different responses from two different ns01.000webhost.com

```
Quering 63.223.113.202 for {jumaat.cheapantivirus.me.,ANY}
; Answer ID: 18467  QR: true  OPCODE: QUERY  AA: true  TC: false  RD: true
; RA: false  RCODE: NOERROR  qc 1  an 3  au 0  ad 0

; Question section:
;jumaat.cheapantivirus.me. IN ANY

; Answer section:
jumaat.cheapantivirus.me. 2h IN SOA ns01.000webhost.com. hadi.blabl.com. 2012020403 28800 7200 604800 7200 
jumaat.cheapantivirus.me. 2h IN NS ns01.000webhost.com. 
jumaat.cheapantivirus.me. 2h IN NS ns02.000webhost.com. 

; Authority section:
;(none)

; Additional section:
;(none)

; Query took: 250 msec
; Server queried: 63.223.113.202[udp]
```

Some minutes later

```
Quering 208.43.152.32 for {jumaat.cheapantivirus.me.,ANY}
; Answer ID: 18467  QR: true  OPCODE: QUERY  AA: true  TC: false  RD: true
; RA: false  RCODE: NOERROR  qc 1  an 5  au 0  ad 2

; Question section:
;jumaat.cheapantivirus.me. IN ANY

; Answer section:
jumaat.cheapantivirus.me. 2d IN SOA ns01.000webhost.com. freehosting.000webhost.com. 2012012701 172800 7200 3600000 172800 
jumaat.cheapantivirus.me. 2d IN A 31.170.162.67 
jumaat.cheapantivirus.me. 2d IN MX 0 aspmx.l.google.com. 
jumaat.cheapantivirus.me. 2d IN NS ns01.000webhost.com. 
jumaat.cheapantivirus.me. 2d IN NS ns02.000webhost.com. 

; Authority section:
;(none)

; Additional section:
ns01.000webhost.com. 2d IN A 208.43.152.32 
ns02.000webhost.com. 2d IN A 64.120.10.10 

; Query took: 219 msec
; Server queried: 208.43.152.32[udp]
```

For both requests I started with query to 8.8.8.8 (Google public NS)

And **second** answer seems as full and correct, but it's serial is older, you know?!

Comment: thank you for your reply. Please tell me what command you use. dig jumaaat.cheapantivirus.me ANY is only repying my main domain IP. I don't understand this: "For both requests I started with query to 8.8.8.8 (Google public NS)". I hope you can explain it in detail. Thank you.

Comment: sg552 - I used dnsquery from Posadis-DNS and requested initial data (list of NSes for your domain) from public google-dns. A typical invocation of dig looks like: dig @server name type. And better to ask authoritative servers for your domain ns01 + ns02

Comment: I understand what you are saying now. `dig jumaaat.cheapantivirus.me ANY` didn't work on my first try. After query `dig @ns02.000webhost.com jumaat.cheapantivirus.me ANY` I get the result I wanted and a moment later `dig jumaaat.cheapantivirus.me ANY` gave me result. Don't know what  happen but thank you.

Comment: @sg552 - when you dig **without server defined in request**, you asked your default nameserver for recursive query (which failed), second **direct request** from authoritative for zone server will show result, third request was served from default-server cache. **Most important** for you is *first FAIL*, because other requesters also can meet such problem. Dig cheapantivirus.me domain, glue records in it for your subdomain, A for subdomain at the end

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand this: ...`glue records in it for your subdomain, A for subdomain at the end`... What are you trying to say?

Answer (score 1):

you can use the "dig" (unix/linux) tool and specify what records you want returned if you like.

```
dig cheapantivirus.me A

dig cheapantivirus.me MX
```

Comment: both command will only gave me result of my main domain (cheapantivirus.me). It will not work with my subdomain (jumaat.cheapantivirus.me)

Comment: hm, I think it should if your subdomain is set up in DNS "dig jumaaat.cheapantivirus.me A" gives me "jumaaat.cheapantivirus.me. 86400 IN A 63.223.113.202" as an answer.

Comment: 63.223.113.202 is my main domain IP. If you see here: http://network-tools.com/default.asp?prog=dnsrec&host=jumaat.cheapantivirus.me you can see that my subdomain A record jumaat.cheapantivirus.me is pointing to 31.170.162.67. How could I use any command to see that? Thank you.

Comment: @sg552 - `dig jumaaat.cheapantivirus.me ANY`