# MX record pointing to Hostgator

Tags: email, amazon-ec2, mx-record

I would like to host only my email on host-gator but website on Amazon. How do make it work? The support don't really have the knowledge of this.

I tried to create a A record to the hostgator , can i have multiple A record? 
What i did was create a MX(webmail.domain.com) record in Route53 that point to my A record (webmail.domain.com) in Route53 which point to the host-gator email. That is what i'm told to do, but doesn't seem right.

DO i need to create a MX or something on host-gator? Quite confusing , not sure how it works.

Advice and knowledge would be greatly appreciated. Thanks ! :)

Comment: You seemed to have did the right thing. Just give it a while for DNS to propagate properly, usually takes up to 24-48 hours. What do you get when you do `dig webmail.domain.dom MX`

Comment: The parent nameservers do not have your nameservers listed

Comment: i did talk to the hostgator customer care. below is solution. 
If you have pointed domain via Route53, go to Route53 and add following records.
1) Point A record with name as mail.urdomain.com and value as ip address of your shared hosting( u can find it in the cpanel). 
2) Point MX record (leave name value empty) and value as 10 mail.urdomain.com 
Note: its imp to add a number which denotes priority. Doing these 2 things u will be able to get ur mails works. i did and it worked.

Comment: Nowadays , people started using Cloudflare, thanks for the update @user1388835

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have two issues:

1. The error message `The parent nameservers do not have your nameservers listed` means that you haven't told your **registrar** where your **nameservers** are.  Your nameservers are probably either HostGator's or Route53's but you should not have both and you should only be changing entries in one of them - the correct one.  [The canonical question on how DNS works should help you to understand this](https://serverfault.com/questions/355887/why-does-dns-work-the-way-it-does).
2. What you need in order to send email to HostGator and web traffic to AWS is:

   - An **MX** record that contains `mail.example.com` and a priority number.
   - An **A** record for `mx.example.com` that lists your HostGator IP address.
   - One of:

     1. A **CNAME** record for `www.example.com` that points to your AWS instance.
     2. An **A** record for `www.example.com` that points to your AWS Elastic IP.
   - You can choose to have an **A** record for `example.com` or not.  If you do have one, it would be best to point it at your AWS Elastic IP.

You *can* have multiple A records for a single name but doing so will not achieve what you are trying to achieve.  This is called Round-Robin DNS and clients will choose one of the returned IP addresses (usually at random) and use that address until the TTL expires.

Comment: Dont really understand. Sorry. I have my registrar nameserver as amazon's and would like to manage the mail/server from route 53. Email handled by hostgator, webhosting handled by ec2

Comment: My current MX name is webmail.domain.com , value 10 webmail.domain.com --- A record name is webmail.domain.com , value [hostgator ip]

Comment: That's probably fine, but you have to fix the problem I labeled as `1.` first, because no one else can look up those MX or A records until you fix the first problem.

Comment: http://check-host.net/check-dns?host=webmail.blogshopdeal.com

Comment: http://leafdns.com/index.cgi?testid=68196F29